# SQL Server default date time stamp?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field that when something is inserted I want it to get the current Date & Time and insert this into the database. Is there a way to get the date & time, and set it as the default value?

Currently the default value is: (getdate()) Which sets only the date. How do I also set the time?

Comment: You need to specify what implementation of SQL you use...

Comment: @JNK: did you create a macro for this as well?

Comment: @voodoo not yet but I'm close

Comment: What data type is your column? `getdate()` does return both date and time but if you are using data type date you will only store date or if you are using a varchar() that is not long enough.

Comment: @mikael - get out of my head.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`GETDATE()` is a date and time in SQL Server.

Run `SELECT GETDATE()` to verify this.

What is the datatype of your field?  If it's `DATE` then it will not hold time values as well.

Comment: What if you don't want to use the current time?

Comment: The question is about returning the current date and time.  What do you want exactly/

Answer (score 4):

One easy way is to give the field a default constraint:

```
create table YourTable 
    (
    ... other columns ...
    CreateDt datetime default getdate(),
    ... other columns ...
    )
```

A disadvantage of this method is that you can overwrite the value by specifying it in an `insert` clause.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would like to use GETUTCDATE() instead GETDATE() to avoid confusions.

Comment: I would recommend that either. It's very hard to get rid of localtime if you use it.

Answer (score 2):

`SYSDATETIME()` will get the current date and time.

Make sure the data type of the column is `datetime`, and not just `date` or it won't be able to hold a datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Most SQL implementations (engines) do have `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` function.