# How to insert current date and time in sql server database using timestamp datatype?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, timestamp

I want to insert current date and time into sql server database from asp.net webpage. I am using timestamp datatype in sql server table.

table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE user3
  (
     uname VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
     email VARCHAR(50),
     doj   TIMESTAMP
  );
```

code used :

```
   cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into user3 values(@uname,@email,@doj)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", uname);           
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);   
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jdate", DateTime.Now);
        if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
```

Please Help me with your suggestions and solutions.

Comment: try  `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doj", DateTime.Now);`

Comment: For storing date in database use better [DATETIME](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105093/difference-between-datetime-and-timestamp-in-sqlserver). TIMESTAMP has different usage.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using timestamp?  That is used for versioning, not for storing a date/time value.

Comment: If the value will only ever be set once (as join date will), set the column in the database to have a default value

Comment: Explicitly name columns in `INSERT INTO user3 (uname, email, doj) VALUES (@uname, @email,@doj)`

Comment: Another solution do not pass date at all, create INSERT and UPDATE trigger to automatically set date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timestamp is method for row versioning. It is automatically generated. But datetime is a datatype. So use datetime instead of timestamp.

```
create table user3(uname varchar(50) primary key,email varchar(50),doj datetime);
```

Comment: Or `datetime2` is better and recommended for new work.

Comment: Changing datatype is not all, for full solution look how parameters are binded.

Comment: Thanks @Iad2025. I saw that parameter just now.

Comment: Don't [fix code inside the question](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9259307). That's what answers are for.

Answer (score 1):

Use `datetime` with a `default` value:

```
create table user3 (
    uname varchar(50) primary key,
    email varchar(50),
    doj datetime default getdate()
   );
```

When you insert a new row into the table -- with no value for `doj` -- then it will get set automatically.  I usually called this column `CreatedAt`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's the case that you are making an insert every time a user signs up;

Try setting a constraint on the table

create table user3(uname varchar(50) primary key,email varchar(50),doj datetime default getdate());

Then you won't have to pass in that value each time

[SQL Server default date time stamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002477/sql-server-default-date-time-stamp)